# Java check if next digit of an int is equal to current one

Tags: java, int

I want to find out if an int contains 2 or more same digits in a row.

Example:

```
int value1 = 12345; // should return false
int value2 = 123451; // should return false
int value3 = 12344; // should return true

public boolean isNextDigitSame(int valueToCheck) {
    // implementation

    String number = String.valueOf(numberToTest);

    int[] numberAsArray = new int[number.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {

        int j = Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10);

        numberAsArray[i] = j;

        System.out.println(j);
}
```

So far I have managed to convert the input into an array but I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: You can implement it either converting the `int` to `char` or doing it mathematically.  Please edit what you have implemented so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public boolean isNextDigitSame(int valueToCheck) {
// implementation
      int previousDigit = -1;
      while(valueToCheck>0){
          int currentDigit=valueToCheck%10;
          if(currentDigit==previousDigit )
              return true ;
          previousDigit =currentDigit;
          valueToCheck/=10;  
     }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Although this is the correct answer, please explain how it works so that it could be helpful to the OP

Answer (score 0):

Because you have stored all the number's digits inside an array, all you have to do now is checking if a digits repeats over time. You can do this by taking each individual digit and comparing it with the other digits (do not compare it with the digit itself!!!). Comparing can be easily done by a simple for-in-for loop since the number is an integer, it will take O(n*n) operations (n can maximum be 10 for integers).
here is what you needed to do:

```
public class DigitChecker {

public boolean isNextDigitSame(int valueToCheck) {
    // implementation

    String number = String.valueOf(valueToCheck);

    int[] numberAsArray = new int[number.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {

        int j = Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10);

        numberAsArray[i] = j;

        //System.out.println(j);    doesn't need to be used in this situation
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<number.length(); i++){
        int digit = numberAsArray[i]; // take each digit and compare it with the other digits
        for(int j = 0; j<number.length(); j++){
            if(digit == numberAsArray[j] && (i == j-1 || i == j+1)) // if you found the digit which equals to your 
                return true;                                        // digit and it's in a row, 
        }                                                           // just stop the program and return true
    }
    return false; // this will execute if only you didn't find any 2/more digits
}
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    int value1 = 12345; // should return false
    int value2 = 123451; // should return false
    int value3 = 12344; // should return truev
    DigitChecker checker = new DigitChecker();
    System.out.println(checker.isNextDigitSame(value1)); // false
    System.out.println(checker.isNextDigitSame(value2)); // false
    System.out.println(checker.isNextDigitSame(value3)); // true

}

}
```